# Complex formula to count uniques is counting one too many

Tags: database, excel, excel-formula, pivot-table, countif

I have an issue with computing the number of unique `patients` and/or `MRN`.  I crossed referenced one patient to their respective ID three times to make sure every patient only has exactly one unique `MRN`, even those they may appear more than once in the Excel database.  My problem is using the formula:

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(MATCH(E4:E317,E4:E317,0),MATCH(E4:E317,E4:E317,0))>0,1))
```

for the names of patients, results in `94`, which I'm confident is correct, but:

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(MATCH(F4:F317,F4:F317,0),MATCH(F4:F317,F4:F317,0))>0,1))
```

for the `MRN` of patients results in `95`, which does not match.  This initially prompted me that maybe a patient accidentally has two `MRN`. However, when I crossed-referenced multiple times to make sure one entry at a time, this is not so.

Any ideas why this occurred?

Comment: I'm not sure you can use an array range for the first argument of MATCH.  I'm suprised it even worked for the patient names...What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: @pnuts - EXCELLENT IDEA! the culprit showed up right away and problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

A PivotTable can be a quick and quite easy way to identify where 2-tuples whose components should be unique pairs are not, in a few cases (other solutions may work better where many are not):

[image: SO19461466 example]

The number of 2-tuples that can be checked in a single 'pass' is almost unlimited and mismatches can be identified by blank rows. In the example MRN 4.00 is associated with two names, `a` and `d` and it can be seen `a` is also associated with MRN 1.00 .

Alternatively, Remove Duplicates and sorting would achieve much the same result, though evidenced by one or more repeat values, rather than by blanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting a column next to name.  Assuming new column next to name is F place the following in F4:

```
 COUNTIF($E$4:$E$317,E4)
```

then cut and paste F4 into F5:F317

Sum Column F

Use the same approach for MRM.